# UWP: How to get list of all Page Objects and the corresponding TypeName in the Assembly

Tags: c#, uwp

In UWP, How do I get a list of all the Page Objects and their corresponding string name in the Assembly.  For Example, if I create a `Page` called `Page1`, `Page2`, and `Page3` and populate these pages with XAML with controls, how can I can I dynamically create a list of all `Page` Objects and their corresponding string name?

I have some code that works for WPF and I want to know how to do something similar in UWP:

```
class MyPage : Page {
public List<Uri> GetXamlFiles()
{
    var pages = new List<Uri>();
    var asm = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Stream stream = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(
        asm.GetName().Name + ".g.resources");

    DataContext = pages;

    using (var reader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(stream))
    {
        foreach (System.Collections.DictionaryEntry entry in reader)
        {
            pages.Add(new Uri(((string)entry.Key).Replace(".baml", ".xaml"),
                UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
    return pages;
}

public ObservableCollection<TXamlPage> XamlPages = null;

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        List<Uri> pages = GetXamlFiles();

        XamlPages.Clear();
        foreach (var uri in pages)
        {
            XamlPages.Add(new TXamlPage { uri = uri, Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath)});
        }
        A1ListBoxPages.ItemsSource = pages;
    }

} //class

public class TXamlPage
{
    public string Name;
    public Uri uri;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (Name == null) return "<null>";
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just search for all types deriving from `Page`:

```
private IEnumerable<TypeInfo> GetAllPageTypes()
{
    var currentAssembly = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
    var pageTypeInfo = typeof(Page).GetTypeInfo();
    return currentAssembly.DefinedTypes.Where(t => pageTypeInfo.IsAssignableFrom(t)).ToList();
}
```